# Let $S = \{z ∈ C \mid z^8 = 1\}$. Write down $S$ explicitly by listing all its elements as complex numbers in polar form and Cartesian coordinates

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $S = \{z ∈ C \mid z^8 = 1\}$. Write down $S$ explicitly by listing all its elements as
complex numbers in:
(a) polar coordinates
(b) Cartesian coordinates.

What I did so far is write $z^8 = r^8 (\cos 8\theta +i\sin 8\theta) = 1$ which also equals $r^8e^{i8\theta}$.

I'm stuck, what am I suppose to do? Please help!

Edit: not sure if this helps but I also know that $z\cdot z^{-1} = 1$, so $z^8 = z\cdot z^{-1}$.

Comment: What can you say about $r$? What can you say about $\cos 8\theta$? What can you then say about $\theta$?

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP shows prior work.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith Thank you! I was about to say the same, i dont understand why people on here are so quick to downvote

Comment: For future reference, here are three style suggestions that *might* help your question get a warmer reception: (1) Start with a sentence like, "I need to solve the following problem:" before you state the problem. The way it is right now it kind of reads like you are giving the reader a command. People on this site dislike that. (2) Capitalize your first-person i's. (I made this change for you here.) People on this site tend to read lowercase i's as a sign of un-seriousness. (3) Write equations between $ signs. This causes the site to format them nicely. (I did this for you here too.)

Comment: More detail on the dollar signs thing: there is a formatting language called LaTeX that lets you type nice equations; this site uses an applet that lets you format equations in this language if you put them between dollar signs. Some basics: to write a greek letter, put \ and then its name. So to get theta, write \theta. Same for sin and cos: \sin and \cos. Actually, same for curly braces {; you have to write \{. If an exponent is longer than 1 character, surround it with { } (*without* the backslash). So I wrote your equations like z^8 = = r^8(\cos 8 \theta + i \sin 8\theta) = 1 except

Comment: with a dollar sign on either side, and then r^8e^{i8\theta} with a dollar sign on either side.

Comment: If you click on "edit" for the question, you can see the details of how I reformatted all the equations for you, for future reference.

Comment: Thanks i really appreciate your help! Im very new to all of this!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a geometric hint. When you square a complex number $z$ you square its length and double its argument (angle). When you cube it you cube its length and triple its angle.

Now think about where you could start in the plane so that taking the $8$th power of the length and multiplying the angle by $8$ will end up at $1 = 1 + 0i$.

I think this will be a useful way to think about the problem even if you solve it algebraically.

Comment: Im probably really wrong but would the angle = 0  and the length r = 1? Is that what im suppose to do?

Comment: @Jane that's one solution. There are several others! See if you can find other ones.

Comment: Can the angle be 2πn where n is any integer? But i cant think of any other r value except 1 that would work. Am i somewhat right?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out and being understanding btw

Comment: You are right that no value of $r$ except 1 will work. You are also right that the angle can be $2\pi n$ where $n$ is any integer. But (a) if the angle is $2\pi n$, you end up with the same point in the complex plane as angle $=0$, so this is not really a new solution, and (b) there are actually a number of other angles that also work!

Comment: Ohh; how about π/16 because the angle if 8θ so θ can be π/16 because sinπ/2 = 1 and cos π/2 = 0 ?? I feel like theres a quicker way to do this lol

Comment: Right idea. I think you want $2\pi / 8$, not $\pi / 16$ to get back to $1$ in $8$ steps. That is in fact the easiest way to find _one_ solution. For the rest, here's a hint. Look at the powers of that one.

Comment: @Jane - you're close with that $\pi/16$ idea, but you want cos to be 1 and sin to be 0, not the reverse. (If cos = 0 and sin = 1, you have 0 + 1i, not 1+0i.)

Comment: Aside: try the dollar sign thing! You can type $\pi$ and $\theta$ without cutting or pasting anything, and it looks better!

Comment: I tried to get help from my teacher, but all i got was that r = 1 and $θ$ =    
2$ π$n/8. Is this right? and how will i use this information to answer the question. I really apologise for being so slow at this!

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle z^8=1 \to (re^{i\theta})^8=1=cos(2k\pi)+isin(2k\pi)=e^{2k\pi i}$

$\to r^8 e^{8\theta i}=1e^{2k\pi i}$

$\to r^8=1$ and $8\theta=2k\pi$

$\to r=1, \theta=k\pi/4$ for $(\theta <2\pi)$

$\to z_1,z_2,...,z_8=e^{k\pi/4}=\cos{(k\pi/4)}+isin{(k\pi/4)}$ for $k=0,1,...,7$

In other words, as you have $z^8-1=0$, so you have 8 roots.